# When Ubuntu boots I get a black screen after BIOS but before Login, no fsck shows up

Tags: boot, 13.04, lubuntu, screen, fsck

:)

I am not sure if I have a real system issue here but as a freshly lubuntu noob I am wondering a lot now

My Medion Notebook just boots fine, at first there comes the BIOS and "memory checking" window from where I could go to the BIOS, all fine

Then the screen becomes black, but the notebook seems still booting

then after some long seconds the lubuntu (I use 13.04, 99,99% out of the box because everything works just fine =) "loading screen" appears, then comes the login screen and I can start it

I am just wondering: is that an issue? Because I am not able to see any message from fsck even if I force it to start on next boot

```
lspci -nnk | grep -i "VGA\|3D" -A2
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller [8086:2592] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device [17c0:2071]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
```

thats my internal graphics

Thanks guys for any hints! :)

Comment: Your machine is a good one :) - There are bios-settings. Assuming you have UEFI-Bios enabled. You simply disable UEFI-Bios and enable EFI-Bios. At beginning of boot you can see which key to use for to get into Bios-Settings. It is mostly key F2.

Comment: I checked "UEFI-Bios" but I am very uncertain that I have this one. Its a "graphical" BIOS, not the "old" and just ugly ones? Well.. my machine is "old", 1.8 GHZ Celereon CPU I think; my BIOS is "PhoenixBios", old & ugly. :-D Thanks for your reply! =)

Comment: hmmm, but older run better ;) you have burnt 32-Bit-iso ?! I would take 12.04 LTS 2 instead as 32-Bit-iso.

Comment: I used a 32 bit desktop image for my install and it went pretty well. Lubuntu works out of the box for me but this black screen during booting and no fsk showing up during boot drives me crazy :( - but most of the thread I read were about black screen when nothing worked anymore ?_?

Comment: How much RAM do you have ? - for to make Lubuntu run good, should be 128 MB RAM. With command in terminal/konsole: free - you can estimate the size of your RAM of your machine.

Comment: 2 GB ob RAM, Lubuntu uses arund 180 - 220 Megabyte when used